# dropdown list value will not echo

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, echo

very simple code, but the dropdown value for $race will not echo. $name echos fine. what am i missing? Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['peeps'])) {
    $race = $_POST['race'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    echo $race;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $name;     
}
?>

<form action="x_test.php" method="post">
<select name="race">
    <option value="">alien</option> //will not echo if selected
    <option value="">earthling</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />  //echos fine when filled out

<input type="submit" name="peeps" value="+" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your options don't have a value to pass.

Try this:

```
<option value="alien">alien</option>
<option value="earthling">earthling</option>
```

Comment: thanks winterblood. i guess a value is need for this unlike if the type was text. learned something new everyday.

Comment: You can leave out the `value` attribute entirely, it will default to the text content of the option.